# Install Cypress after Windows reinstalling

Tags: windows, npm, cypress

I have reinstalled my Windows OS. All files were saved. But I have to reinstall such programs as git, Node, VSCode etc. So now when I am trying to lunch cypress with the script defined in my package.json I get an error "No version of Cypress is installed in: `...\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\12.10.0\Cypress`", `Please reinstall Cypress by running: cypress install`, `Cypress executable not found at: ...\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\12.10.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe`. Sure, this path doesn't exist any more. But what should I do in this case? `cypress cache clear` doesn't work resulting `cypress is not recognized as the name`, `npm install cypress --save-dev` does anything and the result is `up to date, audited 370 packages in 843ms`. What is a possible solution in this case?

Answer (score 3):

npx cypress install --force solved the problem